# Angular form сбросить значения

Tags: html, angularjs, валидация

Есть форма, внутри нее есть два inputa(type=radio) в зависимости от них другие поля являются обязательными(или наоборот). И при нажатии на select, не выбирая ничего, форма становится не валидной. Как правильно обнулять значения при выборе другого inputa ? Привожу кусок формы и скриншот. Так же по скриншоту видно, что значение модели меняется.. А вот значение валидируемых полей нет. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<form action="Url" method="post" name="form" class="form-validate-angular" data-invalid="{{form.$invalid}}">

<input type="radio" name="name" ng-value="'CLIENT_ACC'" ng-model="accountType"/>
<input type="radio" name="name" ng-value="'ACCOUNT'" ng-model="accountType"/>

<select class="styler" ng-required="accountType == 'CLIENT_ACC'" ng-model="account_row">
  <option th:value="null">Не выбрано</option>
  <option th:value="${score}" th:each="score: ${accounts}">
       <th:block th:text="${score}"></th:block> 
   </option>
 </select>
</form>
```

Comment: А зачем два типа кавычек в `ng-value`? Подозреваю что одинарные становятся частью `value`

Comment: потому что в одном случае - это значение модели может быть, а в другом  случае мы  явно сообщаем значение.